# manage hosts with rundeck and ansible at the same time seems strange,any suggestion?

Tags: ansible, rundeck

rundeck and ansible both have the abillity to manage hosts, but when put them work together, I've tried to convert hosts from one format to another,so that hosts can get managed by rundeck and ansible at the same time, but it's not convenient to do this job, what's the best way to manage hosts?

Comment: I use Rundeck to manage my Ansible scripts being run (provides easy to consume job status and logging/debugging information). As such I do not use Rundeck to manage the hosts. Of course I'm using AWS EC2, so have a dynamic inventory that I reference via tags inside the playbooks, so perhaps this may not be relevant for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some people have done it: https://github.com/srknc/rundeck_ansible_sync

Answer (score 0):

the best way to keep rundeck host info up to date. To create ansible host file from rundeck it is very simple. So before the execution you call a bash script which create the node list for ansible and in this case you can use the rundeck filters and for easy jobs even you can use rundeck directly without ansible.

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=$$
nodeFilter=${RD_OPTION_NODEFILTER:-}
projectName=${RD_JOB_PROJECT:-}
if [ -f /var/rundeck/tools/bin/dispatch ]; then
    /var/rundeck/tools/bin/dispatch -v -p $projectName --filter "${nodeFilter}" >/tmp/filtered.node.$PID
else
    /usr/bin/dispatch -v -p $projectName --filter "${nodeFilter}" >/tmp/filtered.node.$PID
fi
nodes=( $( grep "hostname" /tmp/filtered.node.$PID | cut -f2 -d ":" ) )
echo "[all]" >/tmp/ansible.hosts.$PID
for (( CNTR=0; CNTR<${#nodes[@]}; CNTR+=1 )); do
    if [ "${nodes[$CNTR]}" != "$HOSTNAME" ] && [ "${nodes[$CNTR]}" != "$HOSTNAME.example.com" ]; then
        echo "${nodes[$CNTR]}" >> /tmp/ansible.hosts.$PID
    fi
done
echo "DEBUG: all ansible host file"
cat /tmp/ansible.hosts.$PID
cd /opt/ansible; ansible-playbook -i /tmp/ansible.hosts.$PID /opt/ansible/playbook.yml
```

Where the ansible home where the roles and playbooks are stored /opt/ansible
In rundeck jobs you have to specify option NodeFilter which can be used for filter the nodes, e.g. tags:app or tags:web etc.